# VSTO Addin Menu button style

Tags: vsto

Any one can suggest me to apply style for RibbonMenu, RibbonButton Label names should be bold and indent in VSTO Add in project.  My environment is VS2015, C#, MS Excel 2013 and 2016.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ribbon controls do not support formatting in labels, captions or tooltips. They can only display plain text.

Comment: Trying to achieve Menu name should be bold and indent as like our Excel menu Format -> Cell size, Visibility, Protection in menu group, please suggest

Comment: The items in the gray bars are Ribbon separators, the other items only look indented because they do no have an associated icon

Comment: Thanks Eric, i used Ribbon separators to achieve the same.